# are two samples that change through time statistically equal?

Tags: r

I have two samples of an experiment in equal conditions, I mesure their weight and its changes through time. I have for the same time, their two weights, and I have in total 13 time mesures.

I have, for example:

```
Time Weight Sample
1    1     1
1    1     2
2    1.5   1
2    1.09  2
```

What test I should make to know if this two samples are equal?

I have already tested they are, in fact, dependent on time (individually)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is more statistics than programming, so I suggest asking the question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.  There are several basic ways to approach this 2x2 longitudinal design.  You probably don't want to summarize the groups first, because you lose the variability to estimate.  Start with maybe  https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=longitudinal+two-way+anova

Answer (score 0):

You could give [anova](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-way-anova-test-in-r#compute-one-way-anova-test) a [try](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Eyandell/st571/R/anova.pdf).

> Time <- c(1, 1, 2, 2)
>
> Weight <- c(1,1,1.5,1.09)
>
> Sample <- c(1,2,1,2)
>
> y <- c(Time, Weight, Sample)
>
> n = rep(4, 3) #change 4 to however many n samples you have
>
> group = rep(1:3, n)
>
> data = data.frame(y = y, group = factor(group))
>
> fit = lm(y ~ group, data)
>
> anova(fit)

Comment: This doesn't immediately work with the layout of the OP's dataset.  Also it doesn't allow you to address any intercept differences between the groups.

Comment: True, OP didn't do a great job setting up their question but I adjusted my answer.